# Prometheus: how tsdb handles different retentions?

Tags: prometheus

Say I'm using Prometheus to do the following tasks:

1. Collect `cpu_time` from exporter **every 30s**. Keep it for 2h to save storage space.
2. Aggregate `cpu_time:avg1h` **every 1h** by applying recording rules on `cpu_time`. Keep it for 7d to save storage space.
3. Aggregate `cpu_time:avg1d` **every 1d** by applying recording rules on `cpu_time:avg1h`. Keep it for 1y.

Now according to [this blog](https://fabxc.org/tsdb/) about Prometheus v3 storage layout, all the above data samples would be organized and stored by time windows. Retention in this case, would simply be just deleting some out-dated time windows. However, since I need to keep `cpu_time:avg1d` for as long as 1 year, would `cpu_time` be possible to meet its 2h retention goal?

---

In case someone may wonder why I don't keep the original `cpu_time` for 1 year, here's some explanations:

1. 30s for 1 year is just too much. Our real deployment would collect and store hundreds of thousands time series every scrape.
2. Our clients frequently do queries like "give me `cpu_time` in the past 3 months, with one data point represents average of one whole day each". I imagine this would consume a substantial among of cpu and memory to do this kind of aggregation ad-hocly.

Comment: Prometheus can't store specific series with different retention periods. It's not clear what are the best practices for keeping downsampled data for longer periods. I'd like to know it as well.